# Отключить пятые и шестые биты байта, использую операций И и НЕ

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int flags = 482;
    unsigned int masks[2]={5,6};
    std::cout << flags << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Before:";
    for (int i = 128; i > 0; i = i / 2)
    {
        if (flags&i)
        {
            std::cout << "1";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "0";
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        flags &= ~masks[i];
    }
    std::cout << flags << std::endl;
    std::cout << "After:";
    for (int i = 128; i > 0; i = i / 2)
    {
        if (flags&i)
        {
            std::cout << "1";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "0";
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Работает как-то не так...
482
Before:11100010
480
After:11100000

Comment: Вообще-то 482 в байт не влазит :)

Comment: вычитание из исходного числа 48 (`flags -= 48`), как раз "отключение 5 и 6 бита"

Answer (score 2):

Это позиции битов: `unsigned int masks[2]={5,6};`

А здесь эти числа используются напрямую `flags &= ~masks[i];`

```
int mask = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
   {
       flags &= ~(1 << masks[i]);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Все, что вам нужно - построить маску  10011111. Или делайте ее руками

```
unsigned char mask = 159;
```

или вычислите:

```
unsigned char mask = 3;
mask = ~(mask << 5);
```

Дальше для сброса 5 и 6 бита с байте `byte` делаете

```
byte &= mask;
```

Comment: Можно вообще `0b10011111`. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Можно, конечно...

Comment: @Harry, хм, разве 5 и 6 не так будет - `0b1100'1111`, а смещение будет не на 5, а на 4?

Comment: @dreamIIx Ну, вообще-то я привык считать, что биты нумеруются с нулевого по седьмой...

Comment: @Harry, ох, ну раз Вы привыкли

Comment: @dreamIIx А что, у остальных не так?... Это же программирование, а не какие-нибудь носки в ящике...

Comment: @Harry, у остальных? Значит чуть что ссылаетесь на общество? Есть литература в которой описана нумерация битов? Здесь явно сказано 5 и 6. Даже в массивах(индекс элементов которых начинается на 0)при высказывания о 3 элементе(например) подразумевается элемент с индексом 2, однако разговор идёт о его фактической номере. Мне все равно, кто как считает, однако ответ на вопрос может зависить от этого. Как раз это тот случай.

Comment: @dreamIIx Все, вы правы, внесите исправление в мой ответ, только не заставляйте тратить время на выяснение, с какой стороны разбивать яйца...